# Select only specific country values from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have an XML feed in this format:

```
<Country Name="ALBANIA">
    <Destination Name="TIRANA">
        <Destination_1>TIR</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
</Country>
<Country Name="AUSTRALIA">
    <Destination Name="ADELAIDE">
        <Destination_1>ADL</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="ALICE SPRINGS">
        <Destination_1>ASP</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="BRISBANE">
        <Destination_1>BNE</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="CAIRNS">
        <Destination_1>CNS</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="DARWIN">
        <Destination_1>DRW</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="GOLD COAST">
        <Destination_1>OOL</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="HOBART">
        <Destination_1>HBA</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="MELBOURNE">
        <Destination_1>MEL</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="PERTH">
        <Destination_1>PER</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
    <Destination Name="SYDNEY">
        <Destination_1>SYD</Destination_1>
        <Destination_2/>
        <Destination_3/>
    </Destination>
</Country>
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to select only the destinations from ALBANIA for example and post them as a link like this:

```
<p><a href="TIR.html">TIRANA</a> in ALBANIA</p>
```

Using the XML values the link should look like this

```
<p><a href="{{Destination_1}}.html">{{Destination Name}}</a> in {{Country Name}}</p>
```

I was able to create a list for all the countries but I don't know how to display just the values for one country only.

THIS IS THE CODE TO LIST ALL ITEMS

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "test.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('Country').each(function(){
                        var countryName = $(this).attr('Name');
                        if (countryName = localStorage.ArrivalCountry) {
                            var destinationName = $(this).find('Destination').attr('Name');
                            $('<a class="listItem" href="#" id="'+destinationName+'">'+destinationName+'<div class="arrow"></div></a>').appendTo('#destinationList');
                        }


                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Have you considered using XPath to solve this? Here's some more information on XPath with jQuery: http://dev-tips.com/featured/jquery-tip-using-xpath-selectors

Comment: The xml posted is not valid... You'll need an outer "root" element for it to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are planing to use this, loop over all Countries?, loop over all Destinations for a given Country? etc. Add more info to your question if you wish for more help.

These simple xpath's give you the nodes you are looking for.

This XPath gives you the whole country node where Name = ALBANIA

```
//Country[@Name = 'ALBANIA']
```

This gives you the Destination node from which you wish to extract the Name attribute (TIRANA):

```
//Country[@Name = 'ALBANIA']/Destination
```

This gives you the Destination_1 node from which you wish to extract the text "TIR"

```
//Country[@Name = 'ALBANIA']/Destination/Destination_1
```

Answer (score 0):

First off I'd recommend you don't call destination elements Destination_1, Destination_2 and so on. Call it Destination only and call the parent Destinations i.e.:

```
<Destinations>
    <Destination></Destination>
    <Destination></Destination>
    <Destination></Destination>
</Destination>
```

I didn't change the XML but here's just a small example of how to navigate XML using jquery:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<BODY>

<script type="text/javascript">
// need to add a root to the xml for it to be valid
var xml = $.parseXML('<root><Country Name="ALBANIA">' +
'    <Destination Name="TIRANA">' +
'        <Destination_1>TIR</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'</Country>' +
'<Country Name="AUSTRALIA">' +
'    <Destination Name="ADELAIDE">' +
'        <Destination_1>ADL</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="ALICE SPRINGS">' +
'        <Destination_1>ASP</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="BRISBANE">' +
'        <Destination_1>BNE</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="CAIRNS">' +
'        <Destination_1>CNS</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="DARWIN">' +
'        <Destination_1>DRW</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="GOLD COAST">' +
'        <Destination_1>OOL</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="HOBART">' +
'        <Destination_1>HBA</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="MELBOURNE">' +
'        <Destination_1>MEL</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="PERTH">' +
'        <Destination_1>PER</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'    <Destination Name="SYDNEY">' +
'        <Destination_1>SYD</Destination_1>' +
'        <Destination_2/>' +
'        <Destination_3/>' +
'    </Destination>' +
'</Country></root>');
// looping the xml
for (var i=0; i<xml.childNodes[0].childNodes.length; i++)
{
    var country = xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[i];
    //alert(country.getAttribute('Name'));

    // ... continue to loop the childNodes (destination) of country
    for (var j=0; j<country.childNodes.length; j++)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// means you can easily (you can probably figure out the specifics):
var countries = xml.childNodes[0];
var australia = null;
$.each(countries.childNodes, function() {
    if (this.getAttribute('Name') == 'AUSTRALIA')
    {
        australia = this;
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(australia);

// get a list to loop for all destinations
australia = $(countries).find('Country[Name="AUSTRALIA"]');
var destinations = australia.find('Destination');
console.log(destinations);

</script>
</BODY>
</html>
```